# Building chat app with php

Tags: php, ajax, chat

I'm looking for some references for building chat app with php

### 1. With AJAX

I see there are many tutorials using javascript/jquery that use setInterval method to keep calling an ajax method, which used for getting a last inserted data on database and retrieve if any changes.

### 2. With Ratchet

But i found Ratchet [ratchet web](http://socketo.me/) , which i believe use websockets.

Does anyone know what is the advantage for 1st and 2nd option, is the 1st option (using ajax) a good option?

Answer (score 1):

1. With AJAX

   - Manually you need to maitain the sessions
   - Manually mapping required
   - Its one way

2 With Ratchet Or Websocket

- Websocket is HTML 5 feature so you should use bcz its latest feature
- Websocket works based on session for each connection it will be helpful for each chat connection, Just Map the sessions of 2 users ,simple step make your chat application ready
- Its bi directional data communication